# Ensure add-apt-repository keeps trusted=yes from deb input string

Tags: 18.04, apt

I am attempting to add a private repository to my `sources.list` using the `add-apt-repository` command, but I do not have access to the public key that corresponds to that package repository.

If I try to add the repository normally

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://my-private-server.test $(lsb_release -s -c) main"
```

I have problems with the public key not being available (as I expect)

```
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <pubkey>
Reading package lists... Done                                                                            
W: GPG error: https://my-private-server.test bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <pubkey>
E: The repository 'http://my-private-server.test bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I would like to mark that I trust the repository, but if I try to add the repository with `[trusted=yes]` added, if I look in my sources.list, it has been stripped from the entry.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [trusted=yes] http://my-private-server.test $(lsb_release -s -c) main"
tail /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://my-private-server.test bionic main
# deb-src http://my-private-server bionic main
```

If I add `[arch=amd64]` instead of `[trusted=yes]`, it appears correctly in `sources.list`. If I manually add `[trusted=yes]` to `sources.list` the error that comes from the repository not being signed no longer appears, but I do not want to have to manually edit the file.

What is the correct way to add a trusted repository with `add-apt-repository`?

Comment: Did you find the solution ?